# Session start() php

Tags: php

Please tell me. There are 2 php pages in which session_start () is written at the very beginning. If a large script starts running on the first page (for about 20 minutes), then the second page does not open. Tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't run 20 minute jobs on a webserver! Hand the task off to a background service